$P(x)$ is a polynomial of least degree such that $P(k) = \frac{1}{k}; k = 1,2,3,..., 9$, then $P(10)$ is equal to?
$P(x)$ is a polynomial of least degree such that $P(k) = \frac{1}{k}; k = 1,2,3,..., 9$, then $P(10)$ is equal to
My try:
Let $P(x) - \frac{1}{x} = Q(x)(x-1)(x-2)...(x-9)$.
But I'm not getting how to transform $P(x)$ into a polynomial .

Actually you want to consider $x P(x) - 1$.

But still $P(x)$ needs to be a polynomial right ??

Yes, $P(x)$ is still a polynomial. The hypotheses tell you something about the roots of $x P(x) - 1$, which is a different polynomial. There's no need to work with rational functions here.

Then what's the right way to approach ?

The polynomial $xP(x) -1 $ has 9 roots, and by Lagrange, the minimum such $P$ has degree at most 8, hence P has degree 8, now you just match the constant terms

@peterwhy it's different

EXTENDED HINT:

So the equation
$$xP(x)-1 = Q(x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-9)$$ holds, for some polynomial $Q(x)$, yielding
$$xP(x)\ = \ 1 + Q(x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-9).$$ Thus, $xP(x)$ must have degree at least $9$, which yields $P(x)$ a polynomial of degree at least $8$.

We claim we can set $Q(x)=K$ for some constant $K$ that makes the RHS [of the 2nd equation in 1.] evalaute to $0$ at $x=0$, and $P(x)$ will still be a polynomial in $x$. [Indeed, if the RHS of the above evaluates to $0$ at $x=0$, then the RHS is a polynomial in $x$ with a root at $x=0$. Thus, the RHS divided by $x$ which is $P(x)$, will still be a polynomial in $x$.] The RHS [of the 2nd equation in 1.] will evaluate to $0$ at $x=0$ however, if $Q(x)=K$ where $K = \frac{(-1)×(-1)^9}{9!} = \frac{1}{9!}$ and thus
$$xP(x) \ = \ 1 + \Big(\frac{1}{9!} \times (x-1)\cdots(x-9)\Big).$$ Check that indeed this satisfies both $xP(x)|_{x=0} =0$ and $xP(x)=1$ for all $x=1,2,3,\ldots, 9$. Also, check that $P(x)$ is of degree precisely $8$ which is the lower bound established in 1. above.

Evaluate the RHS of 2. as above at $x=10$ to get $xP(x)|_{x=10} = 2$, and so $P(x)|_{x=10}$ $= \frac{2}{10}$ $= \frac{1}{5}$.



Well why can't we simply set $Q(x) = 1$ instead ?

The RHS evaluated at $x=0$ must be $0$ for $x$ to divide the RHS. This forces $Q$ to be -1/9!$

If $Q(x)=1$ then $1+Q(x)(x-1)\cdots(x-9)$ is not divisive by $x.$ @Ash_Blanc

@mike Should it be $1+$ where you have $(-1)+?$

Yes @ThomasAndrews just corrected!

Well @Mike how can u claim that $Q(x)$ is of degree 0 not 1 ??

@Ash_Blanc then can claim $Q(x)$ is degree zero because they demonstrated a degree zero polynomial that satisfies the equation. Since $P$ has minimal degree, so must $Q$.

But how exactly , $P(x) - \frac{1}{x}$ was itself divisible by $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-9)$ right ?? Then how $xP(x) - 1$ can be of degree less than 10 ??

@Ash_Blanc what you have assumed is not correct... according to your assumption we can't have $P(0)$ but that's not given in the question

@Ash_Blanc $P(x)$ is a polynomial, but your $P(x) -\frac 1x$ is not a polynomial.
